# Call a function on onPress of TouchableOpacity inside renderheader function of react-native-accordion

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to call `deleteInvoice` function on onPress of **TouchableOpacity**, but
it's showing

> Error:undefined is not a function(evaluating this3.deleteInvoice())

***How to call this function?***

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ScrollView, ListView, TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon, FormInput, Button, } from 'react-native-elements';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';


let SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');

let db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'TEST.db', createFromLocation: "~TEST.db", location: 'Library' }, this.openCB, this.errorCB, this.successCB);

var myInvNo = [], totalAmount = [], cmpn = [], header = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], content = [], a, downloadedInvoiceList = []


export default class ExampleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchFromServer = this.fetchFromServer.bind(this)
    this.downloadInvoiceListFromServer = this.downloadInvoiceListFromServer.bind(this)
    this.populateInvoiceList = this.populateInvoiceList.bind(this)
    this._deleteInvoice = this._deleteInvoice.bind(this)

  }
  state = {
    activeSection: false,
    collapsed: true,
    invoiceno: '',
    custname: [],
    invoicedate: [],
    invoicejson: [],
    company: '',
    searchInvoice: '',
    down: false

  };

  componentDidMount() {

    this.populateInvoiceList();

  }



  populateInvoiceList() {

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      // tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TDOCHEADER (INVNO,INVID,INVDAE,DOCTYPE,CUSTNM,ISPROSS,INVJSON,TALLYVOUCHERID,PROCESSDT,PROCESSTM,REASON,STATUS)
      // VALUES(?,?) ', ['VISHAL',7387259868], (tx, results) => {
      //   console.log("Record Inserted");
      // });

      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TDOCHEADER WHERE  DOCTYPE=? ', ['INVOICE'], (tx, results) => {
        console.log("Query completed");

        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.

        var len = results.rows.length;
        var arr = [];
        console.log(`Length :${len}`)
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let row = results.rows.item(i);

          console.log(`record :${results.rows.item(i).INVJSON}`)

          var s = JSON.parse(results.rows.item(i).INVJSON)
          jsonObj = JSON.parse(results.rows.item(i).INVJSON)


          myInvNo.push({
            'header': results.rows.item(i).INVNO + '(' + s.TAX.TOTAL + ') - ' + s.UpdateVariables[0].H_cmpn + '\n' + s.UpdateVariables[0].H_custnm,
            'data': 'Invoice Date:' + s.UpdateVariables[0].H_invdt + '\nDue Date:' + s.UpdateVariables[0].H_duedt
              + '\nTotal Amount:' + s.TAX.TOTAL + '\nCompany:' + s.UpdateVariables[0].H_cmpn
              + '\nRemarks:' + s.UpdateVariables[0].D_dremark + '\n' + ((results.rows.item(i).REASON != null) ? 'Reason:' + results.rows.item(i).REASON : ''),
            'InvNo': results.rows.item(i).INVNO
          })


          content.push(s.UpdateVariables[0].H_invdt)
          console.log(`content :${content}`)
          a = [
            {
              'header': myInvNo,
              'data': content
            }
          ]
          console.log(`a :${a}`)
          this.setState({

            invoiceno: row.INVNO,
            custname: row.CUSTNM,
            invoicedate: row.INVDAE,
            invoicejson: row.INVJSON,
            company: s.UpdateVariables[0].H_cmpn
          });
          arr.push(this.state.invoiceno)
          console.log(`arr :${arr.toString()}`)
        }
      });
    });
  }

  errorCB(err) {
    console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
  }

  successCB() {
    console.log("SQL executed fine");
  }

  openCB() {
    console.log("Database OPENED");
  }



  downloadInvoiceListFromServer() {
    this.fetchFromServer();
    this.populateInvoiceList();
  }

  fetchFromServer() {
    fetch('http://itransformsolutions.co.in/zkTallyAndroidTest/AppServlet', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://itransformsolutions.co.in',
        Origin: 'http://itransformsolutions.co.in',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-PINGOTHER',
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': "true",
        Accept: 'application/json;application / xhtml + xml, application / xml; q = 0.9, image / webp, * / *',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8;x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Agent-the-User': 'the Mozilla / 5.0 (the Windows NT 6.1; the WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like the Gecko) the Chrome / 44.0.2403.89 Safari / 537.36',
        server: "cloudflare-nginx",
        'the-Host': 'http://itransformsolutions.co.in'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({


        "data": {
          Client: "9035",
          DOCTYPE: "INVOICE"
        },
        "Transaction": { Transaction: "PullERRORINV" }

      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {

        let x = response
        console.log(`ressssssssssssss:${JSON.stringify({ response })}`);
        for (let i = 0; i < response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List.length; i++) {
          console.log(`clnt:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].CLNT}`);
          console.log(`doctype:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].DOCTYP}`);
          console.log(`docid:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].DOCID}`);
          console.log(`reason:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].REASON}`);
          console.log(`status:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].STATUS}`);
          console.log(`invno:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_invno}`);
          console.log(`invdate:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_invdt}`);
          console.log(`custnm:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_custnm}`);
          console.log(`invjson:${response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON}`);
          let invjson = JSON.stringify(response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON)
          console.log(`asasasasassa:${JSON.stringify(invjson)}`);
          let doctype = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].DOCTYP
          let docid = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].DOCID
          let reason = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].REASON
          let status = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].STATUS
          let invno = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_invno
          let invdate = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_invdt
          let custnm = response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON.UpdateVariables[0].H_custnm
          //    let invjson=response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON


          downloadedInvoiceList.push(
            "INSERT INTO TDOCHEADER (INVNO,INVID,INVDAE,DOCTYPE,CUSTNM,INVJSON,REASON,STATUS) VALUES('" + invno + "','" + docid + "','" + invdate + "','" + doctype + "','" + custnm + "','" + JSON.stringify(response.INVOICEDATA.INVOICE_List[i].ORDERJSON) + "','" + reason + "','" + status + "')")
        }

        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM TDOCHEADER WHERE  STATUS=?', ['ERROR'], (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Invoice Record Deleted having status=Error");
          })
        });

        // console.log(`insert stat111111111:${downloadedInvoiceList[0]}`);  
        for (let i = 0; i < downloadedInvoiceList.length; i++) {
          db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(downloadedInvoiceList[i])
            console.log(`Record Inserted${i}`);
          });
          console.log("Record Inserted ENDDDD");
          //  console.log(`insert stat:${downloadedInvoiceList[i]}`);  
        }

        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.


      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
    //   this.populateInvoiceList();
  }


  _deleteInvoice(section)  {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM TDOCHEADER WHERE  INVNO=?', [section.InvNo], (tx, results) => {
        console.log("Invoice Record Deleted after selection");
      })
    });

    this.populateInvoiceList()
  }

  _toggleExpanded = () => {
    this.setState({ collapsed: !this.state.collapsed });
  }

  _setSection(section) {
    this.setState({ activeSection: section });
  }

  _renderHeader(section, i, isActive, down) {
    return (
      <View >
        <Animatable.View duration={400} style={[styles.header, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]} transition="backgroundColor">
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View>
              <Icon name='keyboard-arrow-up' size={25} color={isActive ? '#214263' : '#16a085'} />
              <Icon name='keyboard-arrow-down' size={25} color={isActive ? '#1abc9c' : '#214263'} />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.headerText} > {section.header}</Text>


            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.addInvoice({ text: section.InvNo })}>
              <Icon name='edit' size={25} color='skyblue' />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Icon name='file-upload' size={25} color='red' />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._deleteInvoice(section)}>
              <Icon name='delete' size={25} color='red' />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Animatable.View>

      </View>
    );
  }




  _renderContent(section, i, isActive) {
    return (
      <Animatable.View duration={400} style={{ paddingLeft: 45, paddingVertical: 5 }} transition="backgroundColor">
        <Animatable.Text animation={isActive ? 'bounceIn' : undefined}>{section.data}</Animatable.Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  }


  addInvoice=()=> {
    Actions.addInvoice()
  }
  render() {


    return (

      <ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.container}>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
            <Icon name='search' size={20} iconStyle={{ paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 10 }}
              color='#214263' />
            <FormInput
              placeholder="Inv No"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ searchInvoice: text })} />
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>

            <Accordion
              activeSection={this.state.activeSection}
              sections={myInvNo}
              //  renderHeader={()=>(<Text >{this.state.invoiceno}</Text>)}
              renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
              renderContent={this._renderContent}

              duration={100}
              onChange={this._setSection.bind(this)}
            />

          </View>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.downloadInvoiceListFromServer}>
              <Icon name='file-download' size={40} color='white' containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#16a085', borderRadius: 30 }} iconStyle={{ padding: 10 }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addInvoice}>
              <Icon name='add' size={40} color='#4cd137' />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity >
              <Icon name='file-upload' size={40} color='white' containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#16a085', borderRadius: 30 }} iconStyle={{ padding: 10 }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

        </View>

      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: '300',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 10,

  },
  headerText: {
    // textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: 'white',
    width: 200,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  content: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',

  },
  active: {
    backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
  },
  inactive: {
    backgroundColor: '#16a085',
  },
  selectors: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  selector: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 10,
  },
  activeSelector: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  selectTitle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '500',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: You should take the time to format your code for better readability. And you are not explaining what you are doing, what you expect to get and what errors you are experiencing. Just copying and pasting something in here won't work.

Comment: @ryantxr: Help me

Comment: Your title is bad. Change it so that it is more readable.

Comment: @ryantxr: Done!

Comment: Please read on how to provide a minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

trying to provide simplest explanation to your ques :

```
class YourCompo extends Component{

delete = () => {
console.log('passed in a arrow function via a variable');
}

insert(){
console.log('passing in a function directly');
}

render(){
return(
<TouchableOpacity onPress{this.delete}>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress{() => this.insert()}>
</TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

These are the two ways you use **OnPress**.
Match your code with one of these and your errors would get resolved.Do pay attention to both the syntax.
Hope that helps

Comment: It works normally in the render method.But It is not working in the renderheader method of react-native-accordion

Comment: can you post the exact error thrown, also i cannot see a renderHeader method in mentioned modules documentation?

Comment: please see the _renderHeader() method

Comment: change the syntax where you pass _renderHeader function to :


              **renderHeader={() => this._renderHeader()}**

Comment: Thanks.. yesterday i have done this and its working very well.

Comment: if it worked for you, then you may want to mark this as answer for convenience of other developers who may run into the same problem in future.
Thanks

Comment: Not this answer...but what u said in comment abt changing syntax of _renderHeader method is useful for me

Comment: what is there in the comment is exactly same what i mentioned in the asnwer.please have a look carefully